# Java Map getValue not possible

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, option-type, treemap

I got a code which gets all minimum values from a list called frequencies. Then it puts the min values with the percentage of total values into a String. To calculate the percentage I want to call minEntryes.getValue()(minEntryes is the Map<String, Integer> with all the min values in it), but it does not work. My code:

```
    StringBuilder wordFrequencies = new StringBuilder();

    URL url = new URL(urlString);//urlString is a String parameter of the function

    AtomicInteger elementCount = new AtomicInteger();//total count of all the different characters

    Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new TreeMap<>();//where all the frequencies of the characters will be stored
//example: e=10, r=4, (=3 g=4...

    //read and count all the characters, works fine
    try (Stream<String> stream = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines()) {

      stream
          .flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)
          .filter(c -> !Character.isWhitespace(c))
          .mapToObj(Character::toString)
          .map(String::toLowerCase)
          .forEach(s -> {
            frequencies.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);
            elementCount.getAndIncrement();
          });
    } catch (IOException e) {
      return "IOException:\n" + e.getMessage();
    }

    //counting the letters which are present the least amount of times
    //in the example from above those are
    //r=4, g=4
    try (Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> stream = frequencies.entrySet().stream()) {
      Map<String, Integer> minEntryes = new TreeMap<>();
      stream
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue))
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .min(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
          .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
          .ifPresent(key -> {
            IntStream i = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, key.size());
            i.forEach(s -> minEntryes.put(key.get(s).getKey(), key.get(s).getValue()));
          });

      wordFrequencies.append("\n\nSeltenste Zeichen: (").append(100 / elementCount.floatValue() * minEntryes.getValue().append("%)"));
                                                                                                 //this does not work
      minEntryes.forEach((key, value) -> wordFrequencies.append("\n'").append(key).append("'"));
    }
```

The compiler tells me to call get(String key) but I don't know the key. So my code to get it into the Map is way to complicated, I know, but I can't use Optional in this case(the task prohibits it). I tried to do it more simple but nothing worked.

I could get a key from minEntryes.forEach, but im wondering if there's a better solution for this.

Comment: Your snippet is incomplete and doesn't constitute a minimum reproducible code, nor does it compile, as variable `s` is already defined in the scope. Could you expand it a bit? also, are you sure the `frequencies` is the list? on which line your compiler complains? If I change the `s` variable with another identifier, code compiles and I can't reproduce your problem. Please provide more information.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I added more code, hope you understand now

Comment: It still doesn't compile. `minEntryes.getValue()` can not be resolved, because method `getValue()` doesn't belong to `Map` interface. You also have another problem, which I already mentioned - variable `s` - it's declared twice in the same scope. If I, however, correct the variable naming and remove `minEntryes.getValue()` invocation, your code compiles well and I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I know that `minEntryes.getVaule()` does not work, and I asked how I could do it. I'm sorry for not seeing the issue with the `s` beeing declared twice, should be fixed now.
Edit: If you remove `minEntryes.getValue()` it does not calculate the percentage of the character, wich removes the whole sense of that whole linie.

Comment: `Map` doesn't have a `getValue()` method. See the Javadoc. Unclear what you're asking, or else a mere typo.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I don't think it's a typo, I rather think it's just a real mess of the logic itself.

Comment: @SimonWick I removed that snippet just for the sake to make the code compile. Please, identify what you want to achieve and think about what you are effectively doing in your code.

Comment: I want to do `wordFrequencies.append("\n\nSeltenste Zeichen: (").append(100 / elementCount.floatValue() * `(any of the values in minEntryes cause they are all the same)`).append("%)"));`

Comment: `return "IOException:\n" + e.getMessage();` doesn’t work for a `void` method. Further, `IntStream i = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, key.size()); i.forEach(s -> minEntryes.put(key.get(s).getKey(), key.get(s).getValue()));` will fail as `rangeClosed` will include `key.size()`, which is not a valid index. This will produce an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. `range` would be the correct choice here, but why not just use `key.forEach(e -> minEntryes.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));` or the even simpler `minEntryes.entrySet().addAll(key);` which is what you actually want to do. It doesn’t have to be a Stream

Comment: The entire second half can be simplified to `int min = Collections.min(frequencies.values());  String chars = frequencies.entrySet().stream() .filter(e -> e.getValue() == min) .map(Map.Entry::getKey) .collect(Collectors.joining("', '", "'", "'"));  wordFrequencies.append("\n\nSeltenste Zeichen: (").append(100 / elementCount.floatValue() * min).append("%) ").append(chars);` or even further, when you replace the `StringBuilder` usage by simple concatenation via `+` (depending on what you want to do with the result; currently, you’re doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, but if the question is how to get the value without knowing the key:

1st method: Use an for loop

```
    for (int value : minEntryes.values()) {
        // use 'value' instead of 'minEntryes.getValue()'
    }
```

2nd method: Iterator "hack" (If you know there is always one value)

```
    int value = minEntryes.values().iterator().next();
    // use 'value' instead of 'minEntryes.getValue()'
```

Comment: Cause of the task couldn't use the 1st one, but the 2nd one worked fine.